# Numbers expressible as sum of 2 squares in 2 distinct ways

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was trying this question [here](https://brilliant.org/problems/day-1-a-partridge-in-a-number-tree/) which goes like:

> Find numbers which are squares and can be expressed as $x^2y^2-x^2-y^2+2$ for non-consecutive positive integers only.

Let the number be $a$
\begin{align*}
a^2 &= x^2y^2-x^2-y^2+2 \\
a^2-1 &= (x^2-1)(y^2-1) \\
&=(x-1)(x+1)(y-1)(y+1) \\
\text{Rearranging, }\\
&= \underbrace{(x-1)(y+1)}_{\text{First factor}} \text{  }\underbrace{(x+1)(y-1)}_{\text{Second factor}}\\
&=(\color{red}{xy-1}+\color{blue}{x-y})(\color{red}{xy-1}-\color{blue}{(x-y)}) \\
&= \color{red}{(xy-1)^2}-\color{blue}{(x-y)^2} \\
\text{So,   } a^2-1&=(xy-1)^2-(x-y)^2 \\
\text{When $x-y= \pm1$, (consecutive) } \\
a = |xy-1| &= |(x(x\pm 1)-1)|=|x^2\pm x-1| \\
\text{Or else, }\\
a^2+(x-y)^2 &= 1+(xy-1)^2\\
\text{Let $x-y=t$ and $xy-1=u$, then } \\
a^2 + t^2&= 1^2 +u^2 = p \text{  (say)} \\
\end{align*}
So, I think we need to look at numbers which can be expressed as sum of 2 squares in 2 distinct ways, with 1 being one of the squares in one case.
For example, $$5^2 + 5^2 =1^2 + 7^2 = 50$$

Now, is there some general form for such numbers? Or some way in which I could generate them? How do I proceed? Also, is there some flaw in my work so far?

(I'm **NOT** looking for solutions to the problem I linked. I want some ideas to proceed with **MY ATTEMPT**)

Comment: [Here](http://users.rowan.edu/~hassen/Papers/SUM%20OF%20TWO%20SQUARES%20IN%20MORE%20THAN%20ONE%20WAY.pdf) is an article I like on sums of two squares in more than one way.

Comment: @IanMiller I read the article, and learnt a lot. I'll have to think some ideas over, but as of now, I don't see a clear way to use those ideas in my question. Thanks all the same.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to use it either but thought there could be some useful bits or other insight I didn't absorb fully.

Comment: $\{1,x^2-1,y^2-1\}$ is a Diophantine triple (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_quintuple). One example is $\{1,3,120\}$, i.e. $a=19$. More generally, $\{1,x^2-1,4x^4+8x^3-4x\}$, i.e. $a=2x^3+2x^2-2x-1$.

Comment: Any number of the form $n^2+1$, unless it is prime or a doubled prime, can be represented as a sum of squares in at least one more way (other than just $n^2+1$).

Comment: @IvanNeretin $3^2 + 1^2 = 10 \text{ (not prime) } = ?^2+?^2 $

Comment: I updated my comment.

Comment: @duje What do you mean by $\{1, x^2-1, y^2-1\}$ is a Diophantine triple? It isn't so always. (Example: $\{1, 8, 24\}$) Do you rather mean that we have to look for such triplets? If yes, then how do I proceed? And how did you arrive at the general form of the triplet? Care to expand in an answer?

Comment: I wanted to say that $\{1,x^2-1,y^2-1\}$ will be a Diophantine triple if $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)+1$ is a perfect square (since other two conditions: $1\cdot (x^2-1) +1$ is a square and $1\cdot (y^2-1) +1$ is a square; are already satisfied) and this condition is exactly the condition $x^2y^2-x^2-y^2+2$ from the question.

Comment: @duje Okay, but what next? I realise that they will be Diophantine triples. But is there a general form for Diophantine triples? (Like there is for pythagorean triples) And how did you arrive at $\{1,x^2-1,4x^4+8x^3-4x\}$ ?

Comment: I tried to explain in the answer. The problem lead to Pellian equation. It has parametric solutions (in parameter $x$), but for some values of $x$ there may be additional solutions, so there is no general explicit form as for Pythagorean triples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)+1=a^2$ implies that the set $\{1,x^2-1,y^2-1\}$ is a Diophantine triple see (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_quintuple)), i.e. the product of any two of its distinct elements increased by $1$ is a perfect square. For fixed $x$, finding $y$ leads to Pellian equation $a^2 - (x^2-1)y^2 =-x^2$. It has infinitely many solutions: $y=1$, $y=x\pm 1$, $y=2x^2\pm 2x-1$, $y=4x^3 \pm 4x^2-3x \mp 1$, ... . E.g. for $y=2x^2+2x-1$ we get $a=2x^3 +2x^2 −2x−1$, and $x=2$ gives $a=19$ and the triple $\{1,3,120\}$, which is subtriple of the famous Fermat's quadruple $\{1,3,8,120\}$.

Comment: Nice. And do you know how or have links to articles wherein these (the ones you mentioned) families of solution are derived?

Comment: And how is $a^2 - (x^2-1)y^2 =-x^2$ a Pellian equation? I thought Pellian equations were of the form $b^2-dz^2=\pm1$. Are you putting $\frac{a}{x}$as $b$ and $\frac{y}{x}$ as $z$ ?

Comment: Pellian equation is generalization of Pell's equation where on the RHS you may have arbitrary nonzero integer.

Comment: Any nonzero integer? Doesn't it have to be a square? Or else, how do you solve it?

Comment: See e.g. here http://www.jpr2718.org/FundSoln.pdf or http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/patz5.pdf